# Creating and Comparing Hash Tables in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, compare, hashtable

I'm looking for a function to compare two CSV's formatted as such:

a.csv

```
x1|y1
x2|y2
x3|y3
```

b.csv

```
x2
x3
x4
```

The x values in this csv will be the exact same as the x values in the a.csv

What I would like to achieve is when the for loop is run, the output is wherever the key from b.csv matches the key ve of a.csv, it will output the b key and its matching a value :

```
x2|y2 
x3|y3
x4| "no match"
```

The way my CSV's are formated there may or may not be a header (most likely not), but the value and key columns will always remain the same.

I'm extremely new to PowerShell and the syntax and use are similar to other languages but there always seems to be an easier way to run what I would consider simple operations in PowerShell.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: what happened to the `x1|y1` from the `a.csv` data? ///// also, you mention hashtable ... but there are no hashtables in your data. what hashtable are you talking about? [*grin*]

Comment: I would like to create a hashtable from the a.csv

I want to compare the first columns of a and b csv and output the value where a key and b key match.  If there is no matching key from b to a then i would want to output something that states it.

Comment: @RandomGuy It sounds like you already know exactly what to do! :) What is the question?

Comment: if your collections are fairly small, then building a hashtable would take longer than `$CollectionOne -match $ItemFromCollectioTwo` while iterating thru the 2nd collection. so ... how large is your data set? [*grin*]

Comment: The issue is I'm not proficient in powershell, so i dont know where exactly to start...also need to change my name on here from random guy lol

Comment: @Lee_Dailey the data set will vary but shouldn't be over 100 records.

Comment: @RandomGuy - take a look at the answer i just posted. it seems to do what you need, but does not use a hashtable/lookup-table to track things. with a LARGE data set, a lookup table would likely be the better choice. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

you will need to decide if there are going to be headers in your CSV files. there are ways to handle "sometimes", but that is a different problem that should be fixed at the source. [*grin*]

this checks each item from the 2nd file against all the items from the 1st file. if a match is found, the values from the 1st file are used. if no match, the value from the 2nd file is used & the 2nd column is filled with a "not found" text message.

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$OneInStuff = @'
x1, y1
x2, y2
x3, y3
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'OneX', 'OneY'

# fake reading in a 2nd CSV file
$TwoInStuff = @'
x2
x3
x4
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'Twox'

$NotInTwo = '_Not In Two_'

$ThreeStuff = foreach ($TIS_Item in $TwoInStuff)
    {
    $X_InBoth = $OneInStuff -match $TIS_Item.Twox
    if ($X_InBoth)
        {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ThreeX = $X_InBoth.OneX
            ThreeY = $X_InBoth.OneY
            }
        }
        else
        {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ThreeX = $TIS_Item.Twox
            ThreeY = $NotInTwo
            }
        }
    }

$ThreeStuff
```

output ...

```
ThreeX ThreeY      
------ ------      
x2     y2          
x3     y3          
x4     _Not In Two_
```

Comment: Thank You Lee, im going to test this out!

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks alot!

Comment: @RandomGuy - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]